# Why does MySQL reject my postfix virtual domain query as "an error in your SQL syntax"?

Tags: mysql, postfix, courier

I have problem with MySQL Courier + Postfix Email Server

Here is error log:

```
warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf: query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'virtual FROM `domains` WHERE domain='domain.example'' at line 1
```

And code in `mysql-virtual_domains.cf`:

```
user = mail_admin
password = mypassword
dbname = mail
query = SELECT domain AS virtual FROM `domains` WHERE domain='%s'
hosts = 127.0.0.1
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VIRTUAL is a keyword in MySQL.

Use a different alias, [escape the identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309977/use-sql-keyword-as-alias-name-of-a-column) using backticks.. or just skip the `AS [alias]` part altogether: maps configured for `virtual_alias_domains` are only used to check *whether* there is a result anyway, not *what* the result is:

> a "type:table" lookup table is matched when a table entry matches a lookup string (the lookup result is ignored) -- from [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains)